# Linear algebra introducing Ax=b

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading Gilbert strangs intro to linear algebra book and I'm on the first chapter which starts off with linear combinations of vectors and how to visualise these. It then introduces Ax=b and shows how Ax is really a linear combination of the columns of A, but that it gives a different viewpoint in the fact that A acts on x rather than the other way around. My question is if A represented a linear transformation then is it correct to think of A transforming the vector x somehow or x  combining the rows of A to produce the output, or is this just two ways of thinking about the same thing. I ask this because it seems more natural to think of A transforming x but I can actually visualise the other way. Maybe this will become clear I'm only on the first chapter after all. Thanks

Comment: Sounds fine. The image in my head would be 
$Ax = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} x_1  \\  x_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} y_1  \\  y_2 \end{pmatrix} = y$ or something.

Comment: Paragraphs, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picking up Ruben du Burck's answer you can also write
$$Ax=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\ a_{21} &a_{22} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}=x_1\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}\\ a_{21}\end{pmatrix}+x_2\begin{pmatrix}a_{21}\\ a_{22}\end{pmatrix}$$
So the matrix $A$ acts on $x$ and transforms it into a linear combination of the columns of itself.